# Como usar um Robots.txt no Github pages

Tags: html, robots.txt, github

Eu tenho um repositório no GitHub e nele tem um site que está visível pelo github pages, só que eu quero que os sites de busca só mostrem a pagina inicial do site. Se fosse um site normal eu poderia adicionar um robots.txt na pasta raiz, só que o github não me da acesso a pasta raiz do domínio, somente a pasta do repositório. Oque eu faço ?

*Não da pra usar meta tags pois eu também quero que o Googlebot não veja outros arquivos que estão no repositório que não são arquivos html

Comment: No SOen existe uma [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784322/stopping-index-of-github-pages) que discute isso, já deu uma olhada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é githubpages então é um subdominio algo como `silas333.github.io`, logo é só subir no seu repositório normalmente o `robots.txt`, eu tenho um site no githubpages e funciona normal: https://inphinit.github.io/robots.txt

O que você não pode criar é um `robots.txt` para a página do teu repositório, que é algo totalmente diferente do subdominio do githubpages, ou seja o dominio `github.com` você não tem controle, o seu subdomínio você tem em `.github.io`